# PHPMailer send mail without attachment

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use the `PHPMailer` Class to send an email from my online server.

This mail contain an attachment or multi attachment.

From some reason i can't receive the attachment in the mail.

I only receive the email with the information without the attachment.

This is my code:

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $staffname;
$mail->addAddress($email,$staffname);
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){      
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"/$path".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]);     
}
//Filename is optional

//Provide file path and name of the attachments
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "New Task";
$message = "<h1 align='center'>YOU HAVE A NEW TASK</h1>
    <table  width='100%' border='1'>
    <tr bgcolor='#f7ac01' align='center'>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Type</td>
    <td>Frequency</td>
    <td>Priority</td>
    </tr>
    <tr align='center'>
    <td>$date</td>
    <td>$desc</td>
    <td>$status</td>
    <td>$type</td>
    <td>$frequency</td>
    <td>$priority</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <h2 align='center'>PLEASE CHECK IT www.eiwms-progroup.com</h3>
    ";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);    
$mail->AltBody = "";
```

After a certain search i try this solution

```
$mail->AddAttachment(dirname(__FILE__),"/$path".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]);
```

And this

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]);
```

And this

```
$mail->AddAttachment("uploads/",$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]);
```

Also i check my upload folder and the file exist in the folder

But all this solution didn't solve my problem

How can i send an email with an attachment using `PHPmailer` Class??

Upload Code:

```
foreach(preg_replace('/ /','-',($_FILES['myfile']['name'])) as $f => $name) {

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$f],$path.$name)){
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO tbl_taskimage(db_taskid,db_image)VALUES('$row[0]','$name')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
}else{header("location:add-tasks.php?msg=32");
}
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. Have you just uploaded the file in the request? Or is it saved somewhere? Something else?

Comment: @JonStirling first my file is uploaded to the upload folder named uploads than i send an email

Comment: Can you show the code that puts your uploaded files into this "uploads" folder for clarity please?

Comment: @JonStirling Please check it

Comment: Okay, and what is the value of `$path`? Can you see the files available on the file system? What's the full path to them?

Comment: @JonStirling $path = "uploads/" this is the path of a file /home/mhmd2991/public_html/uploads/All-project.xlsx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153862/discussion-between-mohamad-mohamad-and-jon-stirling).

Comment: @JonStirling any idea ??

Comment: @JonStirling any help ??!!

Comment: On a side note: the `$mail->AltBody = "";` will make sure I'll never see any of your tasks in my mail client #plaintextmailsftw

Comment: @Gordon can you please explain more i didn't understand what you try to tell me $mail->AltBody=" " shouldn't be in my code ??!

Comment: Because not providing an alt text for html mail is bad practise.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters should be: `$mail->addAttachment( $path, $name (optional), $encoding (optional), $type (optional) );`

So, you should only use `$mail->addAttachment ( $filepath , basename ($filepath) );`. `basename` returns the file name.

Comment: $filepath you mean the $path in my code the uploads/ ??

Comment: $filepath is path to your uploads/ + filename of your file you want to attach.

Comment: @Earee i tried that $mail->AddAttachment("uploads/",$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]); but i didn't receive the attachment

Comment: try: `$mail->addAttachment("uploads/" . $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i‌​]);`. Dot (.) for string concatenation. also, is there any error message stated?

Comment: i didn't receive the attachment and no error appear

Comment: refer to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php on how to use $_FILES global variable.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below script which working fine...

```
            $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                require '../vendor/autoload.php';
                $mail = new PHPMailer;
                $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
                $mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
                $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
                $mail->Body = 'My message body';
                // Attach the uploaded file
                $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
                if (!$mail->send()) {
                    $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } else {
                    $msg .= "Message sent!";
                }
            } else {
                $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
            }
        }
```

Quick links:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Seems something is wrong with code formatting in my browser, for better understanding please use below link.